# Using JavaScript to create an animated counter with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter

I have four counters that I would like to animate (incrementing the count from 0 to a specific number) using JavaScript. My code is the following:

```
const allCounters = document.querySelectorAll('.counterClass');
counters.forEach(allCounters => {
  const updateCounter = () => {
    const end = +allCounters.getAttribute('data-target');
    const count = +allCounters.innerText;
    const increment = end / 200;
    if (count < end) {
      allCounters.innerText = count + increment;
      setTimeout(updateCounter, 1);
    } else {
      allCounters.innerText = end;
    }
  };
  updateCounter();
});
```

In **React**, I wasn't sure how to get it to run. I tried including the code after the  using **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**, but that's not working. (I'm new to React).

I appreciate any assistance you could give me. Thanks so much!

Right before I posted my question, I found a plug-in (https://github.com/glennreyes/react-countup) that could do it, but wondered if it's still possible using JS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using React, try to avoid direct DOM operations (both query and modifications). Instead, let React do the DOM job:

```js
const Counter = ({start, end}) = {
  // useState maintains the value of a state across
  // renders and correctly handles its changes
  const {count, setCount} = React.useState(start);
  // useMemo only executes the callback when some dependency changes
  const increment = React.useMemo(() => end/200, [end]);

  // The logic of your counter
  // Return a callback to "unsubscribe" the timer (clear it)
  const doIncrement = () => {
    if(count < end) {
      const timer = setTimeout(
        () => setCount(
          count < (end - increment)
            ? count + increment
            : end
        ),
        1);
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }

  // useEffect only executes the callback once and when some dependency changes
  React.useEffect(doIncrement, [count, end, increment]);

  // Render the counter's DOM
  return (
    <div>{count}</div>
  )
}

const App = (props) => {
  // Generate example values:
  // - Generate 5 counters
  // - All of them start at 0
  // - Each one ends at it's index * 5 + 10
  // - useMemo only executes the callback once and
  //   when numCounters changes (here, never) 
  const numCounters = 5;
  const countersExample = React.useMemo(
    () => new Array(numCounters)
      .fill(0)
      .map( (c, index) => ({
        start: 0,
        end: index*5 + 10,
      })
    ),
    [numCounters]
  );

  return (
    <div id="counters-container">
      {
        // Map generated values to React elements
        countersExample
          .map( (counter, index) => <Counter key={index} {...counter}/> )
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I think I'm confused about the array portion (.fill and .map) as I need to define four elements with different values.
And, I didn't understand how to implement it in the return. I got it to compile, but I must have made a mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can create it manually directly in the render zone (without any array, with freedom to place it on a custom DOM), or you can manually create the array like `cont countersExample = [{start: 5, end: 200}, {start: 33, end: 367}, /* etc */];`.

Comment: Thanks! In the return, I'm confused about what to write exactly. I tried `<Counter key={1} />` but I think that's not correct. (Sorry...I'm really a newbie at React)

Comment: Something like `<Counter start={33} end={200} />`

Comment: `Sorry...I'm really a newbie at React` I encourage you to read the documentation if you really want to learn: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#learn-react

Comment: OK, I made the changes and compiled, but the counter doesn't update. In this code `doIncrement, [count, end, increment]`, I get the correct values for end, but nothing in count. increment returns a sequential number (2 and then 3) for my two counters.

Comment: Well, in `setTimeout` the milliseconds arguments is set to `1`, so for sure you can't see it change, only the last value. Use `1000` to change the counter once per second.

Comment: `increment` is a constant that equals to `end/200`. `useMemo` ensures the division is calculated only once (optimization).

Comment: `doIncrement` is a function and returns the timeout clearing method. Besides that, if `count` is less than `end`, `count` is incremented by `increment` or fixed to `end`, depending on `count < (end - increment)`.